# Lost Solutions To ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we lose solutions to ODEs (by not dividing by zero), are the lost solutions always constant functions $y(x)=c\ $?

If constant solutions are the only possible lost solutions, why is this so?

If  non-constant lost solutions exist, can you give examples?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Here is an example from Tenebaum and Pollard's Ordinary Differential Equations.

Consider the ODE  $(\sqrt{x^2-y^2}+y)dx-xdy=0$. If we take $x\neq 0$, then we can define $|u|=|\frac{y}{x}|\leq 1$. Substituting $ux$ for $y$ and dividing by $x$ gives the equation
$$
\pm \sqrt{1-u^2}dx-xdu=0.
$$
If we further restrict ourselves to the case that $|u|\neq1$, we can divide by the square root term and obtain the family of solutions
$$
\log x=\arcsin \frac{y}{x}+c,\qquad \left|\frac{y}{x}\right|<1,x>0
$$
$$
-\log (-x)=\arcsin \frac{y}{x}+c,\qquad \left|\frac{y}{x}\right|<1,x<0.
$$
But in solving this ODE, we excluded the "constant" solution $u=\pm 1$, which is really $y=\pm x$. This too is a solution to the original ODE and it is not constant.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting that we lose non-constant solutions to the original equation but this is a "compound loss" where each "simple loss" is a constant solution. Is it only possible to lose a constant solution without changing variables (that is, without dividing twice)?

Comment: I'm not totally sure about what you mean but I think this example is relevant: Consider $(2x+3y+2)dx+(4x+6y+4)dy=0$. Dividing once by the line $(2x+3y+2)$ gives $dx+2dy=0$, which has the solution $x+2y=c$. But the line we divided out itself defines a solution to the ODE.

This is again an example from Tenebaum and Pollard. This book is full of subtle examples designed to challenge your intuition if you're interested.